# C++ object reference instead of copy

Tags: c++, windows, object, reference

This works fine:

```
udtCandidate firstCand;
firstCand=uSeqs[i].Candidates.front();
```

This would create a copy of the udtCandidate.

But I would need a reference to it, not a copy.

However

```
udtCandidate firstCand;
firstCand=&uSeqs[i].Candidates.front();
```

does not work. 
The compiler tells me that there is no binary operator "=" that accepts a right-handed operand of the type "udtCandidate *".

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

The declarations are:

```
struct udtCandidate
{
    udtJoinFeatures JoinFeaturesLeft;
    udtJoinFeatures JoinFeaturesRight;
    udtByteFeatures ByteFeaturesLeft;
    udtByteFeatures ByteFeaturesRight;
    int iHPUnitIDLeft;
    int iHPUnitIDRight;
    double targetCost;
    vector<unsigned long>bestPath;
    double bestPathScore;
    bool hasAncestor;
};
struct udtCandidateSequence
{
    double Score;
    vector<udtCandidate>Candidates;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a reference instead of a value, you have to create a reference variable:

```
udtCandidate& firstCand = uSeqs[i].Candidates.front();
```

Using `&` as you did means address-of operator, which in turn changes the type to a pointer.

Comment: Oh, okay. It seems that I have to declare and assign it in one line. I tried declaring udtCandidate& firstCand; in one line, and assigning it in the next line, but that did not work...

Comment: That's because you can't have an empty reference. I suggest you read up on the subject in your C++ book. Also, initialization in one line is a good programming practice.